# Why are genetic algorithm chromosomes represented using 8 bit binary?

Tags: gene, gene-expression, algorithms, genetics, chromosomes

I am learning about [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

Why chromosomes are represented using 8 bit binary.

This arose when I apply crossover techniques to the bits.

Please help me to find the answer.Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi @Julie I do understand you originally posted on Stackoverflow and were directed here. This is a good question, however it is a statistics problem because the chromosomes are not a physical chromosome but a name given to the algorithm design. https://stats.stackexchange.com is better suited to this question.

Comment: I agree that it's not biology, but I consider genetic algorithms to be a programming problem, not a stats problem (and have been asked and answered on SO previously, [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179823/genetic-algorithms)). Seems to me like StackOverflow would have been an appropriate place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Not always. The representation of chromosomes in genetic algorithms is often dependent on the specific problem to be solved and number of variables to be found through the optimization process.

Not only you can chose a 16-bit representation, but integer-based representations are also used as mentioned [here](https://hub.packtpub.com/using-genetic-algorithms-for-optimizing-your-models-tutorial/).

At the computation level, using a binary representation usually facilitates cross over operations on the bit arrays. 8 bits are compact while already give you a range of [0-255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosome_(genetic_algorithm)#Chromosome_design) different values for a given variable, thus provides a first option to go unless you need a larger value space.